# How can I print a list of characters in a string using a for loop?

Tags: c#

I want to print the all the characters from A to Z to display using for loop. This is what I have got so far:

```
string alpha = "A";

for(int i=0; i <= 25 ; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(alpha[i] + 1));
}
```

I know this code is not correct. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: A string is defined as an IEnumerable, so you can index its members (the chars) without any problem. They are like regular array indexes.

Comment: what are your expected results? Do you want to print each character in `string alpha` or do you want to print from `A - Z`?

Comment: What exactly is "not correct" in your opinion?

Comment: You will get out of range exception using your code when `i > 0` in `alpha[i]`

Comment: What exactly are you even trying? Determined on the number of different answers your question seems pretty unclear. Are you displaying all characters from alphabet to the scree or just those within your string (which is just `"A"` in your case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want the output to be a list from A to Z. This code does that for you:

```
char alpha = 'A';
for(int i=0; i <= 25 ; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(alpha + i));
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? I guess there is a reason OP puts 25 in the for-loop.

Comment: yup this works... thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write each character between A and Z, I would use this:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

That code works because `char` is convertible to `int`.

If you want to iterate over the string and write each character on its own line, I would use the string length, and then iterate over the string to get the character. There is no need to use `Convert.ToChar` since the indexer already returns a `char`.

```
string alpha = "A";

for(int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(alpha[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't restricted to a for loop you could do this with a foreach as well.

```
string alpha = "A";

foreach (var element in alpha)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Comment: `foreach` is not a `for` loop as per the requirement.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for the info. Haven't seen the "for" in the title.

Comment: It might be good as additional answer, but it is not exactly according to the requirement. Just wanted to give you the heads up.

Comment: That will just print `A`,  not all the other letters as the loop is only interated once.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The questioneer wrote this "I want to print the characters from the string to display. " and the foreach loop does exactly this ;)

Comment: @HimBromBeere the string is just `A`....

Comment: I realize and flagged the question appropriately. Obvioulsy it´s quite unclear what OP actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to go from "A" to "Z" then you can use a simple `for` loop with `char`.

```
for (char a = 'A'; a <= 'Z'; a++) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to pass **alpha** as string then use exapme 1 other wise pass char value it will more easy:

***Example 1:***

```
string alpha = "A";
for(int i=0; i <= 25 ; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToChar(alpha) + i));
}
```

***Example 2:***

```
char alpha = 'A';
for(int i=0; i <= 25 ; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(alpha + i));
}
```

Comment: What's up with the double `Convert.ToChar` ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Inner one converting string to char and Outer convert Number to char :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print every character in a string:

```
string alpha = "This is a string";
for(int i = 0, l = alpha.Length; i < l; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(alpha[i]);
}

/** This will print:
* T
* h
* i
* s
* <space>
* i
* s
* <space>
* a
* <space>
* s
* t
* r
* i
* n
* g
*/
```

But if you want to print from A to Z starting from a given character `alpha`:

```
char alpha = 'B'; //you should use char instead of string.
for (var c = alpha; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
// this will of course print from B to Z
```

Or if you really want to use the number `25`:

```
char alpha = 'A';
for(int i=0; i <= 25 ; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(alpha + i));
}
//this will print from A - Z, but if alpha = 'B', this will print from 'B' - '['
```